# How Do I Create A User & Set Password Without User Interaction?

Tags: linux, bash, archlinux, chroot

I have been recently working on a project named: [arch loop](https://github.com/vasanthdeveloper/arch-loop), which is an automated installer for Arch Linux. I have seen a few installers and scripts to make Arch installation easier, but I am someone who installs Arch Linux, more than three times a day, so following the Arch-way takes a long time and constantly requires user interaction.

***The Problem:***

The password is, the information about non-root user is to be created is taken before itself, and when the appropriate time comes, we will be using the following command:

```
arch-chroot /mnt useradd -m -g users -G wheel -s /usr/bin/bash archuser
arch-chroot /mnt bash -c "echo -e 'password\npassword\n' | passwd
arch-chroot /mnt bash -c "echo -e 'rootpassword\nrootpassword\n' | passwd root
```

to send the password to `passwd` binary in the `chroot` system. But I don't know why it does not work. When the password is being verified by the `sudo` command after the installation is finished. The password seems to be perfectly working. But when tried to log in with the non-root user from tty, the password seems to be incorrect.

***Things I Have Already Tried:***

1. Manually encrypting the provided password with the below code and passing it to the `useradd` binary with `-p` option:

```
perl -e 'print crypt("password", "\$6\$SALTsalt\$") . "\n"'"
```

Please guide me on how to set a user's provided password at a later time, without requiring any user interaction.

Thank You :)

Answer (score 1):

There exists the [chpasswd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/chpasswd.8.html) command. It is just there only to make `passwd` available in batch scripts. Just do:

```
echo "root:rootpassword" | arch-chroot /mnt chpasswd
```

or maybe better, without the need for `mount -o bind` the `sys` `proc` and `dev` directories:

```
echo "root:rootpassword" | chpasswd -R /mnt
```

@subjective: Sorry for the opinion, the project looks ok, however much more work is to be done. I guess the aim is to bring Archlinux closer to "normal" users. However, I don't like the choose of python for the project. Going with plain POSIX sh would make this available for all. I don't like hardcoded partitions, `mlocate` (do you really use `mlocate`?), multiple arch-chroot calls where you could just do a single big script, not handling `os.system` error codes (!), multiple pacman calls without even `-Sy` (!) (pacman can fail if upstream updates the repos), and few more things I don't like. Except for that, nice python abstraction and cool aim. I remember the old archlinux installation scripts few (or more) years ago, they were nice, however I think used commands themselves anyway. Good luck.

Comment: I have already tried the ```chpasswd``` command but looks like it also does not work properly. Anyways thanks for giving me your opinion on the project, it matters a lot to me.

Comment: Yes, I use the ```locate``` command sometimes, if I want to quickly confirm a file's path.

Comment: I don't. On a production server where you have gigabytes of data the process `updatedb` can eat 100% disc for weeks and `mlocate.db` can eat 100% from /var partition. Normal users have gigabytes of data too. Normal users also don't use `locate` - they type what they need in `nautilus` search bar, which is the same as `find -name ...`. Really, `locate` is very old and there are some many problems with it.

Comment: `chpasswd` should work. Does it fail with any message?

Comment: Thanks for replying me and writing the answer, I will try using ```chpasswd``` just once more, and this time I will give you the output given by ```chpasswd``` too.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback on ```mlocate```, I will also remove it from the installer. Also, can I get your Telegram/Twitter? Because I want to talk to you more about the project.

Comment: Sure. Och, I don't have Telegram nor Twitter. Well, hm, I have [github](https://github.com/Kamilcuk), there's my email. You can mention me in an issue in the project or use hangouts or email.

Comment: So, I have tested the following command:
```echo "root:rootpassword" | chpasswd -R /mnt
```
and it did not work. There was no output given by the ```chpasswd``` binary. The new source code has been updated in the GitHub repository and you can check it out. When logging in through the tty of the installed Arch Linux, it says the password is incorrect.

Here is an image of my ```/etc/shadow``` file: https://imgur.com/a/JKkduQX

Comment: I have created an issue in the Github repository and mentioned you. Please assist me on GitHub.

Comment: `There was no output given by the chpasswd binary` ? Why should it be any? Did you check it's return status is `0`? `Here is an image` - well, there definitely the password is set to something.

Comment: Yes, it's return status was in fact 0.

Answer (score 0):

The way as below works for Ubuntu, I think it should work for Arch too.

First, you should have had a machine, which has installed the Arch. Then you add the user that you need with  the two commands: `useradd` and `passwd`. After that, you could `cat /etc/shadow | grep [username]` to get the information of the password of the user added by you, it should be a string, let's say it is `XXX`.

Now, on your target system, after `arch-chroot /mnt useradd -m -g users -G wheel -s /usr/bin/bash archuser`, you add the string coming from `cat /etc/shadow | grep [username]` into the `/etc/shadow` of the target system. The command should be like `arch-chroot /mnt sed -i "XXX" /etc/shadow`.

One more thing, you must make sure that the version of the Arch which you get the information of the password and the version of the target system are the same.